# Globally disable Moodle mail for local dev

Tags: email, moodle

Just getting started with Moodle development and am surprised I can't find a documentation reference on how to globally disable sending of outbound mail. For example, if I have a local dev environment using a copy of a production db, and need to run the cron job for testing purposes, I don't want to risk actually sending mail (in other frameworks I would have that mail sent to stdout or to a log instead). 
I have set in config.php:

```
$CFG->debug = 38911;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

but am looking for something like

```
$CFG->debug_mail ="/logs/moodle_mail.log"
```

or similar. How is this problem normally solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$CFG->noemailever = true;

As documented in config-dist.php ( https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/config-dist.php#L560 )

Comment: And there's also $CFG->divertallemailsto = 'root@localhost.local';

Answer (score 1):

If you're running in development and need to see the emails that are generated, my suggestion is to enable email and change your SMTP settings to use something like [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/).

This will let you actually see the emails that are being generated, rather than them disappearing into a black hole.